# Habitual sentences, use of te-form vs imasu form

Tags: grammar

I ride trains everyday.
Which is correct?:

毎日電車に乗っています

毎日電車に乗ります

I think it's the first one. If so, does the second one mean "I WILL ride trains everyday" (expressing intent, and implying that they currently don't ride trains everyday)?
The deck I'm using put the first answer, but it contradicted itself by translating "I study on weekends" as 平日は勉強をします (it didn't use the te-form here).

Comment: Both are correct but there is a small difference. Please see the link.