# Habitual te-form and -imasu form, combined with future intent

Tags: grammar

I asked the question: [Habitual sentences, use of te-form vs imasu form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78544/habitual-sentences-use-of-te-form-vs-imasu-form?noredirect=1#comment128597_78544)

> I ride trains everyday. Which is correct?:
>
> 毎日電車に乗っています
>
> 毎日電車に乗ります
>
> I think it's the first one. If so, does the second one mean "I WILL
> ride trains everyday" (expressing intent, and implying that they
> currently don't ride trains everyday)? The deck I'm using put the
> first answer, but it contradicted itself by translating "I study on
> weekends" as 平日は勉強をします (it didn't use the te-form here).

and was linked to [Habitual aspect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11925/habitual-aspect)
which was really helpful.

However, I read all the comments and was still unsure on one thing.

Could the second one mean "I will (IN THE FUTURE) ride the train everyday"? And is there an adverb to make it more obvious to mean that? Or is it just by context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could the second one mean "I will (IN THE FUTURE) ride the train everyday"?

Yes. For example, if the person who said this sentence lives in a small island now, it surely means "I will ...".

> And is there an adverb to make it more obvious to mean that?

As you probably know, there is no "simple future tense" in Japanese, but there are many ways to describe a future plan/volition. Examples:

- 毎日電車に乗る**ことになります**。
- 毎日電車に乗る**と思います**。
- 毎日電車に乗ろ**うと思います**。
- 毎日電車に乗る**予定です**。
- **来月から**毎日電車に乗ります。
- **これから**毎日電車に乗ります。 (これから = from now on)